# how to update custom attribute in active directory?

Tags: powershell, active-directory, windows-server-2012-r2

Hi guys my name is Bastian and I am a student. I come to ask for help on a script to update users in active directory with CSV file. I created the columns in the active directory schema, all appear in the user profile when I look for them, but when I perform the update the message says that the parameter does not exist. The updates through PowerShell directly works and is reflected, but through the CSV file does not find the columns, I need your help to correct my error, I would appreciate your guidance.

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory
[String]$Ruta = Read-Host "path (Por Ejemplo 
C:\archivocsv.csv)"
$ou="OU=DominioExtendido" + "," + (Get-ADDomain).DistinguishedName
If(-Not(Get-ADOrganizationalUnit -Filter {Name -eq "DominioExtendido"})){New-ADOrganizationalUnit 
"DominioExtendido" -Path (Get-ADDomain).DistinguishedName}
$dominio=(Get-ADDomain).DNSRoot
Import-Csv -Path $Ruta | foreach-object {
$UPN = $_.Cuenta + "@" + "$dominio"
New-ADUser -SamAccountName $_.Cuenta -UserPrincipalName $UPN -Name $_.Nombre -DisplayName 
$_.Nombre -SurName $_.Apellidos -GivenName $_.Nombres -Description $_.Descripcion -Office 
$_.Oficina -OfficePhone $_.Telefono -EmailAddress $_.Email -Title $_.Titulo -Department 
$_.Departamento -Company $_.Compania -City $_.Ciudad -State $_.Region -AccountPassword 
(ConvertTo- SecureString $_.Clave -AsPlainText -force) -Path $ou -Enabled $true - 
ChangePasswordAtLogon $true -Verbose -companyCode $_.CodigoEmpresa -companyID $._RutEmpresa - 
socialReason $._razonSocial -acronymCountryCode $._CodigoPais -contractType $._TipoContrato - 
businessUnity $._BU -officeLicence $._Licencia365}
""
finish!!


PS C:> ErrorTerminación(New-ADUser): "No se encuentra ningún parámetro que coincida con el nombre del 
       parámetro 'companyCode'." New-ADUser : No se encuentra ningún parámetro que coincida con el 
       nombre del parámetro 'companyCode'. En C:\Creacion_Masiva_Usuarios.ps1: 15 Carácter: 473+ ... 
       $true -Verbose - companyCode $_.Codigo_Empresa -companyID $._Rut_Empresa -socialR ...
       CategoryInfo : InvalidArgument: (:) [New-ADUser], ParameterBindingException
       FullyQualifiedErrorId : 
       NamedParameterNotFound,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.NewADUser
```

[User attributes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l1Jmi.png)

[Profile user](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JIfi8.png)

Comment: I really really definitely recommend you to read about [Splatting](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/use-splatting-to-simplify-your-powershell-scripts/) it's very useful for cmdlets like `New-ADuser` it will make your code a lot easier to read!

Comment: DON'T use the `script` tag. It offers no information at all. All SO questions are about scripts one way or another. It's no better than adding `program` or `code`

Answer (score 1):

Use `New-ADUser -OtherAttributes` for attributes that don't have a corresponding parameter!

The `-OtherAttributes` parameter takes a hashtable as an argument, and you simply populate it with key-value entries where the key is the attribute display name and the value is the intended attribute value.

For an attribute with the display name `companyCode`, you'd supply a hashtable like this:

```
New-ADUser ... -OtherAttributes @{ 'companyCode' = $_.CodigoEmpresa }
```

Comment: Hi Mathias, thanks for your answer, now going to try to make my script with your advice.
if fail, i´m gona back to here, thanks!!!!!

Comment: Mathias, I'm really lost with the creation of the script, I have read a lot and put into practice what I have seen, I'm just starting, could you give me a little more guidance, I would appreciate it.

Comment: @Ekatherina I am happy to help, but you have to tell me what you need help with :-) Did `-OtherAttributes` not work as expected? Are you getting new errors?

Comment: Mathias, well, apparently now I have an error that says "Cannot validate the argument of the Name parameter. the argument is null or empty", I check the CSV and it has data, I really think it is a syntax problem or I am not really recovering the data correctly.

C:\full_script.ps1: 41 Carácter: 17
                     New-AdUser @NewAttributes
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [New-ADUser], ParameterBindingValidationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationError,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.NewADUser

Comment: Hello mathias!!!! I am writing to thank you, you guided me a lot, my error was more basic than it seemed, I needed to update my fields not create them, for that reason the error kept appearing.
Now this code helped to update all the extended attributes, the script is simple but fulfills the function, I will improve it based on the conditions that I need.

Comment: $Users =import-CSV C:\updateusuarios.csv
foreach($User in $Users){
Write-Host "Actualizando Usuario:" $User.Cuenta
Set-ADUser -Identity $User.Cuenta -Title $User.Descripcion -Description $User.Descripcion -Company $User.Compania -Replace @{companyCode=$User.CodigoEmpresa; companyID=$User.RutEmpresa; socialReason=$User.RazonSocial; acronymCountryCode=$User.CodigoPais; contractType=$User.TipoContrato; businessUnity=$User.BU; officeLicence=$User.Licencia365}
}